# FPU command FLDL converts double to long double in ST0

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, floating-point

I have a double value in my C++ code:

```
double inch = 25.399999618530273;
```

When used in calculations, it is loaded into FPU st0 register using

```
fldl -0x90(%ebp)
```

I can see that double at -0x90(%ebp) is the correct value. However after FLDL it appears as long double value 25.3999996185302734375 in the st0 register, even though I compile with -mpc64 -mfpmath=387 and manually sets FPU to double precision immediately before calculations and fldl command:

```
fpu_control_t cw;
_FPU_GETCW(cw);
cw &= ~_FPU_EXTENDED;
cw |= _FPU_DOUBLE;
_FPU_SETCW(cw);
```

Can you please explain, why in the _FPU_DOUBLE mode FPU registers are still in extended precision mode and how to fix that?

Or it just **appears** as long double (I view registers in Eclipse CDT) but in fact is operated without those extra digits internally?

Comment: I have to admit, I haven't read the "What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic" bible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your numeral is converted to 25.3999996185302734375 when the program is compiled, because this is the `double` value (using IEEE-754 64-bit binary floating-point) that is closest to 25.399999618530273. Conversion of a `double` to a `long double` has no error.

When you say you can see the “double at -0x90(%ebp)” is the correct value, then, if you are not seeing 25.3999996185302734375, you are not seeing the actual value at that location—the tool you are using the observe the value has presented it inaccurately.

If you are expecting `double` to represent 25.399999618530273 exactly, then you will be disappointed; it does not, and you must design your code to allow for that or use something other than `double` to represent numbers like this.

What tool are you using that measures lengths with a precision of .000000000000001 inch? Is that a very fine ruler with a very great magnifying glass and robotically enhanced eyes?

Comment: 25.3999996185302734375 is shown as 25.399999618530273 in both Windows VS2010 and Eclipse CDT watch windows. I am a bit confused that they both show incorrect double value here. Eclipse shows 25.3999996185302734375L as 25.3999996185302734375 which is why I think it is long double and 25.399999618530273 is double.

Comment: @queen3: 25.3999996185302734375 in hexadecimal is exactly 0x19.66666; it fits in a `double`. 25.399999618530273 in hexadecimal is approximately 0x19.66665FFFFFFFE0798CA9EB295A3085. It cannot be represented in a `double` because the bits do not fit; a `double` has only 53 bits for its significand. If some software is telling you that a `double` contains exactly 25.399999618530273, then it is lying.

Comment: Hm, then what will be the correct way to verify the real float/double values in Windows/Linux debuggers?

Comment: @queen3 Look at the hexadecimal representation? (How you do this will vary between debuggers.)

Comment: @us2012 Well but that won't give me the floating value. Anyway that's another story and/or question.